# Rails MiniMagick How to get info: value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, minimagick

I want to remove black bars from the image and found that bash script that works well

```bash
margin=$(convert input.jpg -fuzz 10% -set page "%[@]" -format "%[fx:h-page.height-page.y]" info:)
magick input.jpg -gravity South -chop 0x$margin -gravity North -chop 0x$margin output.jpg
```

```bash
convert input.jpg -fuzz 10% -set page "%[@]" -format "%[fx:h-page.height-page.y]" info:
```

returns for example `140`, it is a pixel size of black bar
But I can't this value using ruby interface

```rb
convert = MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new
convert << "test.jpg"
convert.fuzz("10%")
convert.set('page "%[@]"')
convert.format("%[fx:h-page.height-page.y]")
convert.call
```

This command returns

```
test.jpg[0] JPEG 1920x1080 1920x1080+0+0 8-bit sRGB 57180B 0.010u 0:00.018\n%[fx:h-page.height-page.y][1] JPEG 1920x1080 1920x1080+0+0 8-bit sRGB 47180B 0.010u 0:00.009
```

How to get back margin value? This string doesn't contain 140

If I call

```rb
convert.command.join ' '
```

I get

```bash
convert test.jpg -fuzz 10% -set page %[@] -format %[fx:h-page.height-page.y]
```

Comment: Do you get an error? Or any output? Or anything? Please edit your question and add more details about what exactly you would have expected to happen and what happened instead.

Comment: Just need to translate bash code to ruby mini_magick code

Answer (score 0):

```
convert = MiniMagick::Tool::Convert.new
convert << "test.jpg"
convert.fuzz("10%")
convert.set 'page', '%[@]'
convert.format '%[fx:h-page.height-page.y]'
convert << "info:"
convert.call
```

This returns correct value. Thanks to chatgpt for help for argument positioning